# how to conditionally include an item in dictionary initialization block

Tags: c#

I have a static dictionary field. How do I conditonally include a 3rd item based on a certain condition?

```
public static  Dictionary<int, Object> dic = new Dictionary<int,Object>{

{1, new Object()},
{2, new Object()},

};
```

Comment: This to me is a code smell. Can you share details about the condition? Something tells me you might want to reconsider your design.

Comment: `public static Dictionary<int, object> dic = new Dictionary<int, object>{ #if Win32 [0] = new object(), #else [0] = 5, #endif  [1] = true ? 10 : 20 };`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the condition is static too. So you could use a [Static Contructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/static-constructors) to initiliaze the Dictionary with conditions.

Answer (score 0):

You can extract the initialization to a method:

```
public static  Dictionary<int, Object> dic = initDic();

private static Dictionary<int, Object> initDic() {
  var d = new Dictionary<int,Object> {
    {1, new Object()},
    {2, new Object()},
  };
  if (condition) {
    d[3] = new Object();
  }
  return d;
}
```